# Can you define a linux kernel module's name on the make command line?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel-module

I'm building the Qlogic fibre channel adapter kernel module to use with scst. The kernel module that gets created is named *qla2xxx_scst.ko*. Is there some option on the make command line that can be used to change the kernel module name or the "scst" part of the kernel module name at compile time?

For example, I want to create *qla2xxx_test.ko* instead of *qla2xxx_scst.ko*.

I don't want to change the source file names either.

When I run `make all` in the *qla2xxx* directory the resultant make command line that runs is:

```sh
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-91-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/niverson/test/scst-qlogic/qla2xxx BUILD_INI=m
```

That appears to run the *Makefile* completely from */lib/modules/4.15.0-91-generic/build* and I don't want to modify those default make scripts either.

I have found posts saying to modify the `obj-m` and `xxxxx-objs` lines in the *qla2xxx* directory *Makefile* to rename the kernel module, but those didn't seem to work since the *qla2xxx* directory *Makefile* just runs the command line above.

Comment: But why? Kernel infrastructure has special folders to override modules from official one in many distributions. `extra` and `weak ... something` are the ones. No need to rename.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't know that. Also, I may want to load both the qla2xxx_scst.ko official and qla2xxx_test.ko on the same system at the same time and have them attach to 2 separate HBAs for an A-B type test. Is that possible if the 2 kernel modules are named the same? Does the kernel care?

Comment: If you want them simultaneously loaded then renaming seems easiest way to achieve. But maybe there are other mechanisms to do something similar like bind-unbind.